# MongoDB automatically starts with compressor disabled

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-compass

I'm new to MongoDB and just followed their instructions to install (server and mongodb compass)
Got the server running (which is working with my Java backend), but now I wanted to check how it looks via the GUI.
My connection string (which I get when running mongod.exe) is the following:
[image]

To use MongoDB-compass one has to use any kind of compressor(Snappy, zlib).

My question is:

How and where can I change the compressor's value in the connection string?
Or why is it default set to disabled on my machine?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Compression is optional.

If you want to use it, you need to have both the server and the driver support the compressor you want to use. What is supported and what is enabled by default varies with versions of both. See for example [here](https://p-mongo.github.io/rendered-docs/driver/tutorial/reference/create-client.html#compression).